# Asynchronous execution of a function inside Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading

This is how the **views.py** file would look like for example. The user will make some post request and trigger a CPU intensive execution which will take a long time to finish. **I want to return a response to the user with some message denoting that execution started and maybe some unique execution id.**

**The point being the user does not need to wait for the execution to end. So I am starting the time-consuming function in a separate thread, and whenever it finishes execution, it will make entry to some remote database.**

Is this a good approach to achieve the same or are there any potential vulnerabilities with this approach?

Note: Although the function takes a long time to finish, it is essentially a small service, with probably one instance needed to run in production.

```
import threading
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


def async_function(x):
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f'[*] Task {x} executed...')

class MainFunctionView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'val': 1})
    
    def post(self, request):

        t1 = threading.Thread(target=async_function, args=(request.data.get('val'),))
        t1.start()

        return Response('exection started')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel! Have you considered Celery or Redis? It is really easy to get started with the latter, it provides ids for each job in the background, and is able to check whether it is finished/not and the result, if any

Comment: I will take a look at Redis. Does it fit nicely in the context of this requirement?  I just need the user to immediately receive a response, while the function keeps running in the background and finishes on its own. That's all. No such task queue is needed at least for this requirement.

Comment: Redis has a task queue to process the requests one after the other. But you immediately receive an identificator for that process, and can request with that id whether the job is finished/not and what is the result

Comment: I checked that rq task queue works pretty well with Redis. But the issue is my development environment is Windows and rq cannot work properly with windows. And due to infra related limitations, there is no way I can switch to using a Linux VM or something like that.

Comment: Indeed. Altough there are some distributions available for Windows, but makes everything a bit more complicated. That's when i decided to switch to linux!